# Strange differential equation (update)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $f$ is a non-constant analytic function in the variable $x$ such that $$f' = f \cdot P(x,f),$$ where $P$ is a two-variable polynomial over $\mathbf{C}$. Can one have $f(0) = 0$?

As noted by copper.hat, the answer is no. But maybe this is not the question I wanted to ask.

**Assume that $f$ is a analytic function in the complex variable $x$ such that $$Q \cdot f' = f \cdot P(x,f)$$ where $P$ and $Q$ are non-constant polynomials in $x$. What can you say about $f$?**

Is it possible to simply "solve" such a differential equation?

Comment: Take the analytic function $f=0$.

Comment: I modified the question, thanks.

Comment: You made one small modification and after the question was answered, you changed the question considerably. If the question changes significantly, you should add a new question.

Comment: That's why I put the new version in boldface :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x) = P(x,f(x))$. Then you have
$f'(x) = f(x) g(x)$. Look at the power series around $x=0$. Suppose
$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n x^n$ and similarly for $g$.

You have $f_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n f_k g_{n-k}$.
 It follows by induction that if $f_0=0$, then $f_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Why the downvote? Something change in the last 9 years???